# Protecting PI when driving motors

Tags: electronics, dc-motor, safety

I am planning on driving two 12V DC motors using the "L293D" motor driver. For that I'm using a 12V battery for the motor supply, and a RaspberryPi to generate a PWM wave to regulate the power output. I am simply connecting both the RPI and the battery to the driver, using only a resistance to limit the current on the GPIO.

Is there anything that I should do or be aware to avoid damaging my RPI?

Comment: If you power L293D with 3V3, then Rpi GPIO pins need very little current to drive it, so there is no need for any current limiting resistance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should be good without adding any other components. In fact, the current-limiting resistors are unnecessary - they may even slow down the transition, but it's doubtful you'd see the difference.

You really should be reading the [spec sheet on the L293D](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/L293D/datasheet/abstract#SLRS0089570). You will note two things relevant to your question - and some suggestions that may improve the outcome of your project:

1. Para 6.5 Electrical Characteristics:

   Note the high- & low-level logic input currents are <100uA - well within GPIO capabilities
2. Para 8 Detailed Description:

   > On the L293D, these [clamping] diodes are integrated to reduce system complexity and overall system size

   Also note the diffs in Figures 4 & 5 wrt the internal clamping diodes